Why use linear/angular acceleration instead of wheel acceleration?
I'm currently looking at the physical constraints of my robot.
Nav2 seems to support higher-level concepts such as linear and angular acceleration, which seems great for keeping human expectations in mind. Unfortunately, it doesn't do a great job of maximizing the performance of my robot. Is there some calculation that I can make when it comes to relating my maximum wheel acceleration to these higher level parameters for Nav2?
Thanks

I don't understand the question, can you more clearly reword and what you're referring to?
